# PipeWire no sound on TV via HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 22.10, pipewire

On Ubuntu 22.10 I have a strange bug for sound on HDMI, the sound is working fine on my LG monitor plugged via HDMI but not on my Continental Edison TV (HDMI as well).

So I tried with a live CD of Ubuntu 22.04 and the sound is working fine on the TV, so I tried a live CD of Ubuntu 22.10 and no sound on TV.

On 20.04, it uses pulseaudio:

```
pactl info
Server String: /run/user/999/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 9
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: ubuntu
Host Name: ubuntu
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 15.99.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: 75cf:b2d5
```

On 22.10, it uses Pipewire:

```
pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1002/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 117
Tile Size: 65472
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.58)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.5
Cookie: 4456:dbf8
```

So how to remove Pipewire on 22.10 and install pulseaudio 15.99.1 like on 22.04?

***SOLUTION***

Just found this tutorial which worked fine for me (Disable PipeWire & Enabled PulseAudio in Ubuntu 22.10):

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18449

To enabled bluetooth headset:
https://devicetests.com/fix-pulseaudio-bluetooth-headset

Comment: Please, put your "solution" as an **Answer** if you are sure that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this tutorial which worked fine for me to get the sound on the TV as well: Part "Disable PipeWire & Enabled PulseAudio in Ubuntu 22.10".

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18449

Comment: Fixed my Radeon (Pitcairn) HDMI audio problems.

Answer (score 0):

##### [Ubuntu 22.04]

I have a `pipewire` deployment, having removed all `pulseaudio` packages except
`pulseaudio-utils`, for the (still remaining)  dependency on `pactl`.

```
$ sudo apt list pipew* pulse* -i
Listing... Done
pipewire-audio-client-libraries/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
pipewire-bin/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-pulse/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio-utils/jammy-updates,now 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
```

##### Install WirePlumber as the session manager:

`sudo apt install wireplumber`
*note: you might have to remove `pipewire-media-session`, which `wireplumber` replaces.*

##### Start WirePlumber for your user:

`systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service`

See https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e